# View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol when tapping Return button on keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

This error pops up in the console when tapping return on keyboard(Real device). Everything executes as it should. Keyboard hides but this error keeps on showing in the console.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

       lazy var nameTextField: UITextField = {
         let textField = UITextField()
         textField.placeholder = "Name:"
         textField.delegate = self
         return textField
        }()
             
        lazy var surnameTextField: UITextField = {
          let textField = UITextField()
          textField.placeholder = "Surname:"
          textField.delegate = self
          return textField
         }()
       
         override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
               
              view.addSubview(nameTextField)
              view.addSubview(surnameTextField)

         }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       view.endEditing(true)
       return true
    }


 }
```

Comment: try adding self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: Thanks,  still the same though. Seemed to fix it at first. But console still giving that message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resign should you return **true**.

```
    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I replaced self.view.endEditing(true) with textField.resignFirstResponder. Still have the warning/error message. Like I mentioned on top, the code executes fine and does exactly what it is suppose to...whether using endEditing or resignFirstResponder.